# Access character arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers

why I can not assign it like this:

```
char c1 []="Odin";
   c1=c1+1;
```

Note that I include

> #include<string.h>

Comment: Because you cannot assign to arrays. What do you want to do?

Comment: What should `c1=c1+1;` do? Do u want the string to go from `"Odin"` to `"Pdin"` ? Or to remove the letter `O` ?

Comment: @Tudor yes I want to remove the letter O

Comment: `memmove(c1, c1 + 1, strlen(c1));`?

Comment: Or an alternative to what @MikeCAT said `strcpy(c1, c1+1);`. Still if you also want to be safe you can try `strncpy`

Comment: @MikeCAT I was Just watching a tutorial and the instructor said you can not do this and I wondered why ?

Comment: You can do that with *pointers*: `char c1[] = "Odin"; char* p = c1; p = p + 1;`

Comment: @Tudor No because `strcpy()` with overlapped source and destination invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) for your problem:

> Assignment Objects of array type cannot be modified as a whole: even
> though they are lvalues (e.g. an address of array can be taken), they
> cannot appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator:

So, since `c` in your code is an array object i.e. a type of an array, it cannot appear on the left-hand side of an assignment operator.